# Linux - IBM Blade Center + Identify MM Name from the Linux OS

Tags: linux, ibm, blade-server, bladecenter

I have a Linux machine (RedHat version release 5.6) installed in IBM BLADE Hardware

I am trying to find a solution to identify 
the management Module name --> (MM Name) from the OS (Linux)

Remark - MM name  appears in the General Settings screen

```
 Example how to find the MM Name from the IBM Blade:



 From the IBM BladeCenter - first main screen (MM - Management Module)



 1.       Open MM Control link by click on the (+)

 2.       Click on General Settings

 3.       Then we get screen with MM information and there we can see the MM Name
```

My question:

how to discover the MM name ( as already configured in General Settings screen ) from my Linux?

Or by which tool/command/SW we can identify the MM Name from Linux OS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install  IBM Advanced Settings Utility (ASU) on Linux, with this utility you can get the config of MM and also you can set that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the [IBM BladeCenter SNMP sensor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.taddm.doc_7.2/SensorGuideRef/r_cmdb_sensor_bladecentersnmp.html). With this element of software you should be able to access the information provided by IBM related to the BladeCenter environment.

According to the cited page:

> The sensor uses SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) to discover
>   and query BladeCenter infrastructure components. The Management Module
>   (MM) and the Advanced Management Module (AMM) are the central points
>   of management for the IBM BladeCenter chassis.